# To sort locally or to requery?

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, swing, sorting

I am developing a java application which will be graphically depicting and organizing hundreds of objects. Each of these objects is loaded in from a SQL database, for use in this program.

The user sorts this data, in order to gain information about the dataset, i (as the programmer) have come across three distinct methods to accomplish this:

1. Use individual SQL queries to return pre-sorted data to the program.
2. Use a sorting algorithm locally to sort the entire dataset.
3. Use a local SQLite database to copy the entire dataset to, then query the local database for sorting instead.

Which would be preferable, or are there any other solutions I may have missed?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, care to clarify? If you're only dealing with hundreds of objects and you have them in memory, why would you ever bother requerying just to sort? Especially if it's not a web app and you can keep the data in ram.

Comment: I accidentally hit submit while writing the question =p

Comment: The user sorts this data always by the same field or it might be sorted by different fields?

Comment: Also, the user may, at any time, request a different sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general all of the solutions may work, it depends on the concrete requirements - my thoughts:

**1. Use individual SQL queries to return pre-sorted data to the program**

Works well if the user defines sorting criteria upfront. What if she wants to resort after data retrieval (leads to #2)? It may make sense to define a default sort for each request or a parameter influencing the sort sequence based on certain criteria like user role.

**2. Use a sorting algorithm locally to sort the entire dataset**

As outlined before, a combination of #1 and #2 may be what you need.

**3. Use a local SQLite database to copy the entire dataset to, then query the local database for sorting instead**

Totally different strategy, several things you have to care about:

1. data synchronization
2. security; working in large enterprises, I know that certain security people (e.g. auditors) get crazy when talking about local data replication
3. offline capabilities (advantage)
4. local storage

Personal option: I'd go with a combination of #1 and #2. Furthermore, I'd try to define the interface in a way that supports scrolling (e.g. "retrieve rows #20-100").

Not a definite answer, but my opinion based on the facts you provided...

Comment: @Peaches491: Thanks. Btw: I don't know whether you want to directly access the database (JDBC) or not... it may make sense to have an intermediate protocol (like JSON) in between. Direct client to database connections do not scale in world wide distributed solutions (JDBC is chatty)...

Comment: You are quite right. I am currently using just `JDBC`, and have found the queries to be quite slow at times. What is the purpose of `JSON`?

Comment: @Peaches491: Given the fact that relational database protocols are chatty, it makes sense to introduce a layer in between. `JSON` is only one example. In a world wide (WAN, internet) solution it makes sense to have an intermediate consolidating database access. E.g. each call to `ResultSet.next()` requires are round-trip from client to DB, so introducing an application server (like Tomcat) that provides consolidated data over HTTP should reduce latency (client > appserver > db). If it's already an issue you should investigate this kind of solution (45 chars left, so I have to close :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much always sort in the database if you can. It will almost always be faster than first loading unsorting data into your program and then sorting it manually in your code.

The reasons for this is because database engines are optimized to do just this sort of thing (pun not intended). They are designed to be disgustingly fast at retrieving data, filtering data, and sorting data. Not only will it be faster in terms of run-time, but it will generally be significantly faster to code as well.

Never do #3 for the purpose of sorting data. That just introduces unnecessary overhead and complexity with no gain as far as I can tell.

Comment: Generally yes, but for a small dataset over a slow link the answer may be to sort locally.  The OP should really test the different possible solutions to see if there is any real difference.

Comment: @rossum: That's true, hence the "almost always." These cases are pretty rare for most applications. But yes, that should be noted.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would only query the database once, and then keep the objects cached in memory. You can construct the initial query with a default (or dynamically configured) sort, and then sort the collection in memory after that.

There are other factors to take into consideration, though. If the database is accessed over a network, then you really should cache the objects locally. If you do end up caching the objects, you'll have to make sure to keep the state of your cache and database in sync.

Answer (score 0):

If your result set is only a few hundred objects then you gain alot from just applying your own sort algorithm. To speed things up have your first read from the DB be sorted according to your defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that SQLite approach will be better solution.

- Writing your own algorithm may not be good enough as SQLite provided.
- Caching is not good enough as compared to SQLlite.